# How to encrypt a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, aes, webcrypto-api

I'm looking for a way to encrypt arbitrary large files on client side in the browser before to send it to a web server. Ideally I would like to encrypt in aes-256-cbc and to be compatible with openssl format.

Using the Stream API I'm now able to read a file chunk by chunk, to process it and to pipe it into the XHR POST request body which is great.

I now need a way to encrypt it using AES. Unfortunately the WebCrypto API is not compatible with ReadableStreams for now.

https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/73

In the mean time what could be the best alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is unlikely we will see streams support in WebCrypto implementations for security reasons. See [Encrypting streams](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/06/27/streamingencryption.html) for some reasons.

You also should avoid JS and WebASM crypto implementations as they are unlikely to offer proper security guarantees. For reasons why see [Why JS Crypto is Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) and look at [Mitigating Side-Channel Attacks](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/ssca).

You will need to end up implementing your own chunking and using WebCrypto for your case.